# Django: session variables -> How to override logout without breaking the django authentification core

Tags: python, django, authentication, overriding

first I am newbie in Django (<3 months)
I read the Djnago doc but it is hard sometime....
I use "from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views" to authenticate
so I did not write any login/logout views, only urls.py

and it works well but I would like to override logout (and maybe login) views to initialise and set session variable more efficiently but do not understand how to proceed

someone can explain me the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Please provide more informations - I mean, instead of describing what you think is the solution, explain your __real__ problem instead.

Comment: I use sessions variables that I initialize using middleware to initialize and set values (don't know if it is the way) but I would like to be able to delete session variables when logout view is called ; but as I use the django logout/login auth views I did not write these 2 views

Comment: please edit your question with those details, and eventually post some example code.

Answer (score 0):

What we did for a similar problem in a project was to just wrap auth.views.logout in our own logout view.

Warning: django 1.11 code (this project has yet to be migrated) so you may have to adapt it for your Django version.

```
@never_cache
def logout(request):
    # first let auth.views.logout do it's job
    response = auth.views.logout(request=request)

    # cleanup some of our own stuff
    clean_session(request)

    # contrib.auth.user_logged_out doesn't provide the response,
    # which some of our other apps need to clear some cookies
    signals.account_logged_out.send_robust(
            sender=User,
            user=request.user,
            request=request,
            response=response
            )

    return response
```